# Database for Monthly GDP

Tags: data-request, gdp

Can anyone point me to a source of monthly GDP? So far I only find [yearly](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD) and [quarterly](http://stats.oecd.org/index.aspx?queryid=350). I need it for the period of Jan/1999-Jan/2015 for USA, Japan, the Eurozone and UK.

Thank you!

Comment: This question over at the opendata stack exchange may be of interest: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/searching-a-proxy-for-monthly-gdp

Comment: I have never heard of GDP being published monthly. I don't think you can find it.

Comment: I vaguely remember the Bank of Brazil producing monthly estimates of GDP. There are also estimates of monthly Swiss GDP. I don't think these are official data (as in within an National Accounts framework/standard), but they are what they are. I've heard of daily GDP estimates, too; in a country very dependent on weather conditions. Can't remember which country, but findable I think. You can, of course, produce your own high-frequency measure - range of techniques available.

Answer (score 1):

For the US there is a firm that calculates something from monthly data that the quarterly Bureau of Economic Analysis (BEA) GDP data is also based on: http://www.macroadvisers.com/monthly-gdp/